# PHP Pretty link url using .htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i develop an application using php mysql. below is example of my link.

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=product&product_id=123&type=virtual


http://www.domain.com/index.php?page=checkout&product_id=456&type=download
```

i would like to change it to :

```
http://www.domain.com/product/123/virtual/
http://www.domain.com/checkout/456/download/
```

I know it can change using rewrite mode on .htaccess, but did i need to rewrite to htaaccess when i create a new page?

wordpress have 7 line (i think) on their .htaccess file.

Can i get a global coding on .htaccess to achive my goal?? im very lazy to create a new rewrite rule everytime i create a new page. i just need to follow this rule

```
http://www.domain.com/page/parameter/parameter/...
```

Comment: You can map your pretty urls to your existing ones.  You'll have to change your existing links, to match the pretty ones within your application.  Assuming you want the pretty urls as the canonical form.  Adding additional rules is easy, but it may become a management headache mapping.  I don't think your example buys much in terms of usability.

Comment: @Progrock sorry. i dont understand what are you explaining to me. did my application url are hard to rewrite?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Is the site already live with the old style links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect all requests for non existing files to index.php file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if file or directory exests, use it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# else send request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then, in *index.php* you parse URI and show the necessary page.

Comment: thanks for your time. Did i just need to copy paste your code on my htaccess file then all my page have pretty link?

Comment: Besides .htaccess, you need a logic in index.php to route to right page.

Comment: yes i already route the page on index using if($_GET['page'] == 'product'){ include 'product.php'; }

Comment: For example, if URL is `http://www.domain.com/product/123/virtual/` in index.php you can parse it in array by this way: `$route = explode( '/' , $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`. Now `$route[0] == product, $route[1] == 123, $route[2] == virtual`  and then you code: `if($route[0] ... `

Comment: alright. i get it. so i just need to past your code on htaccess then route the page. when i need the get parameters, i just use explode the url right?